# Using Android phone as Bluetooth headset to PC

Tags: windows, bluetooth, voip

I'd like to use my HTC One S (running Android ISC) as a Bluetooth 
"headset" for my computer, so I can use it to make VOIP calls.

For devices without that capability built in, are there computer/phone applications that make this possible? [Wo Mic](http://www.wirelessorange.com/womic/) is a start, but only supports the voice input, not output.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Google Voice application for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice&hl=en)?  It can be found in the Google Marketplace.

Comment: I want to use Wifi (via the GMail app.) And yes, I know there are apps on the Play Store that can do this, but I'd like a generic (and free) solution for any VOIP app.